# Precautions to prevent iPhone virus from attachment

Tags: iphone, email, pdf, virus, anti-virus

In a momentary lapse of sanity, I opened up an attachment (a .pdf) from an unknown email address (the domain doesn't seem to be a website) in the gmail app on my iPhone 5. Realizing that there was a reasonable probability that there was a Trojan, I quickly closed the file.

I now have the following related questions:

1. Is there any chance I just put a virus on my iPhone?
2. If so, what should I do to scan my phone and verify?
3. In the future, is there a recommended way to scan such attachments as a precaution before opening them?

Looking at a number of questions on this website, I have learned that for my (non-jailbroken) phone, it is fairly unlikely that I got a virus, but I'd appreciate knowing that for sure.

Comment: Most likely you are safe, because in order to do something nasty, an active element has to be triggered. Apple's default PDF viewer (and even Adobe Reader for Mobile) are too dumb to deal with active elements.

Comment: I wouldn't worry too much. Gmail is typically pretty good about scanning for viruses, and even if there was a virus in the PDF it would probably only target Windows.

Answer (score 1):

You are most likely safe, as there are extremely, extremely rare cases of getting a virus this easily, as iOS is extremely secure. There are no incidents of getting a virus from PDF on iOS, so you are definitely secure.